# Fixing diagonal movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help fixing my diagonal movement in unity. It goes faster diagonally than horizontally or vertically.

I'm working on an isometric 3D game. I'm using Unity 2019.4

Anyway here's my code:

```
if (canMove)
{
 Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
 Vector3 rightMovement = right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
 Vector3 upMovement = forward.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

 Vector3 heading = Vector3.Normalize(rightMovement + upMovement);

 transform.forward = heading;
 transform.position += rightMovement;
 transform.position += upMovement;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Unity but just looking at your code I see that you normalize `forward` to compute the `upMovement` but not `right` for `rightMovement`.

Comment: you simply need to take into account that diagonal movement is approx.  .77 for every horizontal and vertical you move.  Pixels are square so this gives the appearance of faster movement diagonally because a pixel is longer diagonally than horizontally or vertically.    I don't know why you have so many variables though.  I think you simply need to add your direction to your position.

Comment: `Vector3.Normalize(rightMovement + upMovement).normalized` do you get paid by the number of times you normalize vectors?

Comment: Blindy. Lmaoo. I didnt even realize that i had it normalized twice.

Answer (score 0):

The first major clue in your problem should be that you compute a `direction` vector but then never actually use it. That wouldn't be so bad (wasteful but not the end of the world), except that the other major problem is that you compute the `rightMovement` and `upMovement` values differently.

It seems to me that the code could be greatly simplified, having two benefits: making it more efficient, and making it easier to get right. Without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's impossible to say for sure what the right code is, but I would expect this to work in your case:

```cs
if (canMove)
{
    transform.forward = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;
    transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Important tip: code doesn't always get better by *adding* more code to it. It's fine to add some statements experimentally during debugging to try things out, but it's generally a bad idea to just keep adding more and more statements. If something's not working, look at the statements that are already there and figure out how they can be made better (i.e. be made to work), rather than trying to fix whatever's wrong with them with even more statements.

Comment: Didn't help me. It just stopped the movement.

Comment: @Santeri sorry, minor typo (that's the problem with no MCVE...no practical way to test the code posted). I left out the crucial `+` operator for changing the `position` vector. I've fixed the code example above.

Comment: Still not normalized.

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean. The `forward` vector is normalized, but the movement itself is necessarily scaled by the time and speed. If the above doesn't address your problem, consider improving the question so it includes all of the relevant details. It's difficult to debug someone else's code when there's no way to actually _debug_ it (i.e. by running it and seeing what doesn't work).